# How do I test a Unix command?

Tags: unix, testing, cat

I want to test a unix command. More specifically the "Cat" command. I want to be able to get test data for this.

How do I go about doing this?
(Newbie to computer science)

I'll be using terminal

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the operating system you are on you could type this in a command prompt or terminal.

If you are on OSX or a Linux derivative you'll need the terminal, if you are on Windows you'll need [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) to perform this action.

When you want to test commands that are possibly dangerous it's always best to try these in a virtual environment like [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html)

You could use any data for the cat command, if you're setup you could use the `/etc/issue` file with `cat /etc/issue` to print your distribution information (This is GNU/Linux specific).

Be sure to read the [CAT manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cat)